# jquery has() doesn't seem to be working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6VDKA/1/)**, and for some reason, my dropdown menu isn't working when clicked.

In the fiddle, when you click on "Format" it is supposed to drop down, but it isn't doing that. Nothing is happening, I thought that using the `has()` jquery method would work but it isn't doing it. Am I using it incorrectly?

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).has("ul").css({display: "block"});
});
```

Comment: use `find()` instead.

Comment: [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) filters the matched set, it does not traverse to a descendant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.has` is not the function you are looking for in this case.  This is what has is used for:

Imagine you have an HTML structure like so:

```
<div>
  <em>hey</em>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>hello</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <strong>hey</strong>
</div>
```

Now say you use a jQuery selector (`$('div')`) then you're going to get a jQuery object back with 3 different elements in it:

- First div (with em)
- Second div (with the ul)
- Third div (with strong)

Now say you want to filter these down to ONLY divs that have a `ul` inside of them.  You can do that with `.has`:

```
$('div').has('ul')
```

Now you're going to have a result set that has 1 element in it:

- Second div (with the ul)

Using `.has` does not traverse down to the ul like you're expecting. You should just use `.find` instead like so:

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('ul').css({display: "block"});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Qwdg6/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/Qwdg6/1/

API:

- `.find` : http://api.jquery.com/find/
- `.children` : http://api.jquery.com/children/ : http://jsfiddle.net/Qwdg6/1/

Whatever suites your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find("ul").css({display: "block"});
});
```

*OR*

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).children("ul").css({display: "block"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is related to how the event handler is defined. If you target the button in your callback, you can reach the dropdown list from there:

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(e){
    $(e.target).next("ul").css({display: "block"});
});
```

If you want the dropdown to slide back up when you click the button again, you can do this:

```
$("ul > li").on("click", function(e){
    $(e.target).next("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I liked the toggle idea, so I am using it!